# Eye colour from Adobe Fuse are almost washed out

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, uv

[image: the eyes]

[image: render viewport[![][2]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAhaa.png)

I'm very new to Blender and I just made my character in Adobe Fuse, and added some extra pieces of clothing in Blender. Whenever I go to the Material viewport shading as well as Rendered, the eye colour is heavily washed out. The eye colour in my UV map is much darker, so is there anything I might have missed? Do I have to make a separate UV map for the eyes?

EDIT: Added screenshots of nodes in the node editor. I'm using one UV map for the entire body, and separate ones for his coat and hat. I'm so sorry for any confusion I may cause, I'm very new to this

[image: material node[![][4]]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS842.png)

Comment: Can you post an image of the Material Nodes used for the Eyes?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/

Comment: can you disconnect all the other nodes so only the eye image texture is used? I suspect some other nodes are mixing and washing out the result.

Comment: I assume you are both the same NoneType?  A moderator (@David et al) may be able to merge accounts for you.  Please elaborate on answer in answer.

Answer (score 1):

> can you disconnect all the other nodes so only the eye image texture is used? I suspect some other nodes are mixing and washing out the result. – rob 9 hours ago

@rob I made an account but I realised I couldn't reply back to this. But if you're reading this, it worked! Thank you so much for your help :)

Edit: the solution was to disconnect a node

Comment: That is not an answer.

Comment: ah finally i can comment. i just put it up there so maybe the person that commented would see. This is just me replying to my own post (that i posted as a guest). Their suggestion worked out for me

Comment: Hi @NoneType, new users are restricted from commenting until they have sufficient reputation. Please edit your answer to say that you disconnected certain nodes and that improved the result. Good answers are ones that will help other users when they search for solutions to similar issues.